# XCODE 4.6.3 & iPhone simulator v6.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6.1, ios6

I have XCODE 4.6.3 installed but couldn't launch iPhone apps on iPhone 6.1 simulator.
It crashed every time I'm trying to debug with phrase "The simulated application quit."

I checked installed simulators and there are all up to 6.0 (4.3, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0). There is no 6.1 installed and I don't know how to install it and why it wasn't installed with XCODE 4.6.3

Thanks for any suggestions!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved the issue.
Go to the "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator" folder and delete 6.1 subfolder with corrupted simulator state.

Hope it'll help someone.